# Install libpq dependency with CMake

Tags: postgresql, cmake, libpq

I'm building a program with CMake on Windows. The program has a dependency on `libpq` that's che C PostgreSQL library.

I load the PostgreSQL package, CMake find it and the program it's built. But then I want to copy `libpq.dll` and its dependencies on the build folder in order to use it. I've copied `libpq.dll` in a post build command, but it's not sufficient because it depends on other libraries.

What's the best way to copy `libpq.dll` and all files that are needed to it in order to solve all dependencies?

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

project (postgresqldatabase)
set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package (PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file (GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SRC *.cpp)

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRC})
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

# Copy PostgreSQL .dll files on bin folder if we are on Windows
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
  # It prints C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib
  message (STATUS "paths are ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  # It prints  C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libpq.lib
  message (STATUS "libraries are ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES}")
  add_custom_command (TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS}/libpq.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
  # I need to copy also dll's needed to libpq.dll
endif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
```

Comment: You also need the dlls that are under C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this resolves your problem, but it worked for me:

```
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
include_directories (${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Also, this solves the problem that I had when I got to this question, so hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use a dedicated libs folder. What I have found is that I need the following DLLs:

- libeay32.dll
- libiconv-2.dll
- libintl-8.dll
- libpq.dll
- ssleay32.dll

This was also verified with DependencyWalker, maybe on a project that demands more features you may need some other dll, but for basic SQL operation those were the set.

Comment: Is this list still valid for PG versions 10+? I'd like to update HeidiSQL's libraries, but for some reason with the v10.2 libpq.dll I get error 126: "module cannot be found". Probably there is a way to get an even more verbose error message here (using Delphi)?

Comment: To answer my own question: PG 10+ versions don't use libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll any longer. Instead, I had to add libcrypto-1_1.dll and libssl-1_1.dll. See [here](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/831) for more details.

Comment: libpq.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll, libintl-9.dll, libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libiconv-2.dll were the ones I needed for PG14